# VB script : Evaluating whether a given Number is Even

Tags: vbscript

```
' Even Number Checking

e = inputbox("enter a nunber ")

if not(numeric(a) and a<=0) then
msgbox "sorry eneter a valid number"

elseif even = (e mod 2 = 0) then 

msgbox "even number"

else
msgbox "not an even number"

end if
```

Comment: What are the errors and when do they occur?

Comment: VBScript is a pretty weak language in this area. There isn't even a proper Val(x) function available in all cases. You might want to specify WHERE you're using VBScript from, like MS Excel, or Word, or from a text file with file extension .vbs?

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is you are storing the user input value in `e`, but then in the next line you are checking if `a` is numeric or <= 0.